# How to use const WCHAR* variable in wcstok in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a string (std::wstring variable) with different paths. I am converting that string to WCHAR so that i can tokenize the string and also i can resolve the path (starting with % symbol) using ExpandEnvironmentStrings.

**When doing that I am getting the below error:
Error   C2665   'wcstok': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types.**

It is because we are passing const WCHAR* variable in wcstok.

**Could anyone please help me how to use const WCHAR* variable in wcstok?
Below is the code snippet for that:**

```
std::wstring wstrFileLocation;
std::vector<std::wstring> pathsVector;
const WCHAR * wpszProcToSearch = wstrFileLocation.c_str();
TCHAR szOut[MAX_PATH];
const wchar_t delim[] = L".xml";
wchar_t* ptr;
wchar_t *token = wcstok(wpszProcToSearch, delim, &ptr);
while (token != NULL)
{
ExpandEnvironmentStrings(token, szOut, ARRAYSIZE(szOut));
pathsVector.push_back(szOut);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
`WCHAR* wpszProcToSearch = &wstrFileLocation[0];`
to get a pointer to non-const `WCHAR`s.

Since C++17, you can also use `data()` which also returns a pointer to non-const `WCHAR`s.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to function `wcstok` should be a pointer to a modifiable (non-const) array of `wchar_t` elements.

You are passing `wstrFileLocation.c_str()`, which is a pointer to a non-modifiable (const) array of `wchar_t` elements.

You should allocate a temporary array of `wchar_t` elements, copy the contents of `wstrFileLocation.c_str()` into it and pass it to the function instead.

Answer (score 0):

A 'quick' fix (but ***not good***) would be to cast away the *constness* of your pointer with a `const_cast<WCHAR*>(wpszProcToSearch)` (or something similar) - but this is asking for trouble.

Better, is to copy the buffer given by `wstrFileLocation.c_str()` into a non-const array (easy, using `wcsdup`), as follows (not forgetting to `free` the buffer when you're done with it):

```cpp
    std::vector<std::wstring> pathsVector;
    WCHAR* wpszProcToSearch = wcsdup(wstrFileLocation.c_str());
//  const WCHAR* wpszProcToSearch = wstrFileLocation.c_str();
    TCHAR szOut[MAX_PATH];
    const wchar_t delim[] = L".xml";
    wchar_t* ptr;
    wchar_t* token = wcstok(wpszProcToSearch, delim, &ptr);
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        ExpandEnvironmentStrings(token, szOut, ARRAYSIZE(szOut));
        pathsVector.push_back(szOut);
    }
    free(wpszProcToSearch); // Don't forget to free the buffer!
```